# Problems with variables and scanf function

Tags: c

I'm very new to the c programming language. I wrote this code and i am wondering if there were any way
to write this code shorter and more effective?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("This is my first program.\nPlease put in your name...\n");

    char letter[5];


    scanf("%c%c%c%c%c%c", &letter[0], &letter[1], &letter[2], &letter[3], &letter[4], &letter[5]);


    if(letter[0] == 't' && letter[1] == 'r' && letter[2] == 'a' && letter[3] == 'v' && letter[4] == 'i' && letter[5] == 's'){
        printf("Access Granted\nWelcome Travis.\n");
        return 0;
    }



    else{
        printf("You are not autorized.\nThis program will exit now...\n");
        getchar();

    }

    }if(letter[0] == 'b' && letter[1] == 'o' && letter[2] == 'b'){
        printf("Access Granted\nWelcome Bob.\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For working code and code review - please see codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: After fixing a couple of braces: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac471e129d93ece1

Comment: Did you read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (you should test its result)? Did you compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)? Did you **use the debugger** (`gdb`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%c%c%c%c%c%c", &letter[0], &letter[1], &letter[2], &letter[3], &letter[4], &letter[5]);
```

Is wrong as `letter` is 5 elements long with indexes 0-4. So,in the `scanf` above,`letter[5]` is not a valid location. You are going out of bounds of the array. To fix it,just declare that array of size 7(6 chars for "travis" +1 for the `\0` at the end) instead of 5:

```
char letter[7];
```

Then,that `scanf` can be shortened using `%s` :

```
scanf("%6s",letter);
```

Next,

```
if(letter[0] == 't' && letter[1] == 'r' && letter[2] == 'a' && letter[3] == 'v' && letter[4] == 'i' && letter[5] == 's')
```

And

```
if(letter[0] == 'b' && letter[1] == 'o' && letter[2] == 'b')
```

Can be shortened using `strcmp` function from `string.h` header and merged using the logical OR operator:

```
if(strcmp(letter,"bob")== 0 || strcmp(letter,"travis") == 0)
{...}
```

Putting it all together,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    printf("This is my first program.\nPlease put in your name...\n");

    char letter[7];


    scanf("%6s", letter);


    if(strcmp(letter,"bob")== 0 || strcmp(letter,"travis") == 0)
        printf("Access Granted\nWelcome %s.\n",letter);
    else
        printf("You are not autorized.\nThis program will exit now...\n");

    getchar();
    return 0; //you don't need these in every if and else.
    }
```

Comment: Wow thaks alot for the fast reply's! I really like this forum :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
       unsigned int len_max = 128;
       unsigned int current_size = 0;

       char *pStr = malloc(len_max);
       current_size = len_max;

       printf("\nEnter your string value:\n");

      if(pStr != NULL)
      {
        int c = EOF;
        unsigned int i =0;
        //accept user input until hit enter or end of file
        while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF)
       {
          pStr[i++]=(char)c;

          //if i reached maximize size then realloc size
         if(i == current_size)
         {
            current_size = i+len_max;
            pStr = realloc(pStr, current_size);
         }
      }

      pStr[i] = '\0';

      printf("\nLong String value:%s \n\n",pStr);
      //compare pStr with your defined string for authentication.
      //e.g if(pStr=="myString"){printf("Access granted!");}
      //free memory 
      free(pStr);
      pStr = NULL;


      }
   return 0;
 }
```